# Insert New Column To Kendo Datagrid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I Got Columns are quantity,Totalprice in my kendo grid. Then I want to add calculated column to my datagrid.
for example:

```
    $("#gridcolumnadd").click(function (e) {
    //1.add new column code Column Name is "Price For per kg" 
    //2.Set Column type is number
    //3.Set Column aggregate is sum for footerTemplate
    //4.add calculated values ex:(Totalprice/quantity) to "Price For per kg" with using for loop row count.
    //redraw datagrid 

});
```

Is possible to make it in kendo datagrid?
**

---

**NOTE

I WANT TO CREATE DATAGRID FIRSTLY THEN ADD NEW COLUMN WITH ITS CALCULATION. THATS THE REASON  "I WRITE JUST BUTTON CLICK"**

**
For example; It is not working

```
var raw = grid.dataSource.data();
  var length = raw.length;//if ı have many data . I can use For Loop
  raw[0].new="Test"; //I think one data we have it
  grid.columns.push({ field: "new" });
  grid.dataSource.data(raw);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some tips:

1. Instead of adding a column you should [show](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-showColumn) and [hide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-hideColumn) a column otherwise you will have to destroy current grid and create a new one (pretty expensive).
2. Have it created from the beginning. You might have fields in your model that are actually not coming from the server or you can have fields that are not in the model. You should decide.
3. Don't understand what do you mean by *Set Column aggregate is sum for footerTemplate*. As far as I understand you want to define an aggregate of a column so you should take a look into [`columns.aggregate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.aggregates).
4. Is this an editable grid? If not I do recommend to compute it when you receive the data from the server using either [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event handler or even using DataSource [`schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse)

Lets see how this fits together...

This is my original schema:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID: { type: "number" },
            ProductName: { type : "text" },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
        }
    },
    ...
```

The first thing is add the `Total` which equals `UnitPrice` times `UnitsInStock` where I'm going to use `parse`.

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID: { type: "number" },
            ProductName: { type : "text" },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
            Total: { type: "total" }
        }
    },
    parse : function (d) {
        $.each(d, function(idx, elem) {
            elem.Total = elem.UnitPrice * elem.UnitsInStock;
        })
        return d;
    }
},
```

as you can see I've added an extra field `Total` and then in `parse` I iterate to compute the total for each record.

Next is define an aggregate that computes the total for all the data received.

```
aggregate: [ 
    { field: "Total", aggregate: "sum" }
]
```

This simple!

Now lets define the columns of my grid:

```
columns: [
    { field: "ProductName", title : "Name" },
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Price" },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units" },
    { 
        field: "Total", 
        title:"Total", 
        hidden: true, 
        aggregates: [ "sum" ],
        footerTemplate: "#= sum #"
    }
]
```

Here what is important is `Total` column where:
* I define as (initially) *hidden* using `hidden: true`.
* I also define an `aggregate` that is the `sum`.
* And finally I define a template for printing it.

Finally, I don't need to *redraw* the grid, it is enough invoking `columnShow`...

```
$("#gridcolumnadd").click(function (e) {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columnShow(3);
});
```

All this together here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/63mg9/

Comment: I mean CALCULATED COLUMN WAS NOT DEFINED. DATAGRID WAS CREATED THEN CAN I ADD NEW COLUMN ? IT CAN BE (QUANTITY*0.2) '0.2' IS GIVEN FROM ME. IT CAN CHANGE dynamically. COLUMN NAME WAS NOT DEFINED! BUT YOUR ANSWER IS TRUE IF COLUMN AND CALCULATION ARE KNOWN. HOWEVER IT IS NOT ANSWERING MY QUESTION. I WANT TO CREATE DATAGRID FIRSTLY THEN ADD NEW COLUMN WITH ITS CALCULATION.

Comment: Why so many uppercase? Usually means you're shouting, are you?

Comment: thanks for answer but ı am bored this kendo ui. I think so there is no way add new column with ıts values. I need add new column with make some calculations then I wanna change ıts template.For example ; ı have a ıf condıtıon . ıf(value<0){return "low";}else{return "high";}. something like that.

Comment: Sorry for being bored of KendoUI but I cannot do anything for that: I'm not part of Telerik so no issue on that. Yes, you can add calculations, I showed one way of doing it. No, you cannot add columns dynamically but you can display / hide them. Yes, you can define `if` conditions on your template, check http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/63mg9/1/ the column corresponding to `Units`.

Comment: Yes I know your way thanks. Maybe Kendo  see this. Because when ı ask what ı need, they are saying "I m afraid, this is also not supported" :)).I think  some people may find way . it is so bad for kendo because  kendo support push new data to datasource or column . but unfortunetly can not draw it.

Comment: Still not clear to me... do you know before hand those potential groups to be added? If so, can you create them from the beginning and then recompute/refresh and display them? For doing what you want, you need to change the model dynamically this is "odd" both for KendoUI and for any other framework.